# Canvas rendering from component is not working on Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to render canvas and draw rectangle on it using svelte.js, but it does not work if I write rendering code on the component side.

[Here](https://svelte.dev/repl/88f9749f62ba41edbf94a3a588999889?version=3.44.1) is the reproduction REPL.

It works if I move entire code in Canvas.svelte to app.svelte.

App.svelte:

```html
<script>
    import Canvas from './Canvas.svelte';
</script>

<Canvas/>
```

Canvas.svelte:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let canvasEl;

  const canvas = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000
  };

  const drawRect = (context) => {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.rect(0, 0, 40, 10);
    context.fill();
  };

  onMount(() => {
    console.log('Onmount');
    const context = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    drawRect(context);
  });
</script>

<canvas bind:this={canvasEl} width={canvas.width} height={canvas.height} />
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Thank you,

Comment: You have `canvas` as a const and `canvasEl` as a variable. If you remove `canvas` and replace it's instances with `canvasEl` it works https://svelte.dev/repl/abde58a449544beaa8019744f98c6b65?version=3.44.1

Comment: No problem, happy Svelting!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63192792/responsive-full-width-canvas-in-sveltejs) sounds similar and is solved with using tick(). When I add that to your REPL it's working as well. But in the comments of the answer is stated " if you remove the {width} and {height} from the canvas element itself, the tick is not necessary" (which seem to be absent in JHeth's solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find a reason of error, but found the source:

```
onMount(() => {
    //...
    // this 2 lines cause silent error
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    //...
  });
```

Remove them and you will see the canvas and rect